# How to Extract Columns from Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which is 300 rows and 5 columns

```
X[X[:,0]==1,[1,2]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-de5e74bc1a0b> in <module>()
----> 1 X[X[:,0]==1,[1,2]]

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

How to make this work? I want to filter the first column (equals 1) but returns a copy of second and third column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simplest to separate the two indexing cases. Look at column one first, select the appropriate rows, and then pick out columns 1 and 2 from that array:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (3, 5))
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

>>> a[a[:,0] == 1][:,[1,2]]
array([[0, 1]])
```

---

The code in the question, `a[a[:,0] == 1, [1,2]]`, look syntactically similar but is doing something  different.

For example `a[a[:,0] == 0, [1,2]]` is, in the case of `a`, equivalent to `a[[0,2], [1,2]]`. This indexing picks out exactly two elements from `a`: the element at row `0`, column `1` and the element at row `2`, column `2`. It does not select the rows and columns of the array.

Comment: @DoctorLai: I think this is by far the simplest way. Instead of `a[:,0] == 1` you could write `np.where(a[:,0]==1)[0]` but this is less concise. Your approach looks syntactically very similar to mine but it is actually doing something different. For example, with my array `a`, `a[a[:,0]==0, [1,2]]` is equivalent to `a[[0,2], [1,2]]` which picks two elements out of the array: the element at `(0, 1)` and the element at `(2, 2)`.